# Why am I getting this error in my SQL Query

Tags: php, sql

When trying this query:

```
 UPDATE l1_a
 SET l1_a.goals_for = l1_a.goals_for + l1_results.score1
 FROM l1_results, l1_a
 WHERE l1_results.team1 = l1_a.team_id;
```

I get the error:

```
   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM l1_results, l1_a WHERE l1_results.team1 = l1_a.team_id' at line 3
```

l1_a contains goals_for and team_id

l1_results contains score1 (which is how many goals_for) and team1 (which is team_id)

Is there something wrong with my query? I have double checked that all the columns and tables are the correct names in the query

Thanks

Comment: You can't have a "FROM" clause in an update.

Comment: @jonfen - That depends on the RDBMS, though this does looks like MySQL, so your comment would be right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`documentation for UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) states that this is the syntax for multiple-table `UPDATE` statement:

```
Multiple-table syntax:

UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

Try this:

```
 UPDATE l1_results, l1_a
 SET l1_a.goals_for = l1_a.goals_for + l1_results.score1
 WHERE l1_results.team1 = l1_a.team_id;
```

Comment: UPDATE l1_results, l1_a
 SET l1_a.goals_for = l1_a.goals_for + l1_results.score1
 WHERE l1_results.team1 = l1_a.team_id;
 worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're combining select and update syntax. There is no `from` in an update statement.

Try this:

```
UPDATE l1_a
SET l1_a.goals_for = l1_a.goals_for + 
  (select l1_results.score1 
  from l1_results 
  where l1_results.team1 = l1a.team_id)
```

If there's no record in l1_results, you might empty your data. Better add an IFNULL:

```
UPDATE l1_a
SET l1_a.goals_for = l1_a.goals_for + IFNULL(
  (select l1_results.score1 
  from l1_results 
  where l1_results.team1 = l1a.team_id), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there anyway of doing this query without the FROM?

Comment: I think so. I've added a statement, but I cannot test it at the moment.

Comment: @GolezTrol Don't do that - just use the multi table update syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
UPDATE l1_a
SET l1_a.goals_for = l1_a.goals_for + l1_results.score1
FROM l1_results, l1_a
WHERE l1_results.team1 = l1_a.team_id;
```

to

```
UPDATE l1_a
SET l1_a.goals_for = l1_a.goals_for + l1_results.score1
WHERE l1_results.team1 = l1_a.team_id;
```

You don't need FROM l1_results, l1_a